# Save activity_log object outputs in a list

Tags: r, bupar, daqapo

I have the code below

```
library(bupar)
library(daqapo)
hospital<-hospital
hospital %>%
  rename(start = start_ts,
         complete = complete_ts) -> hospital
hospital %>%
  convert_timestamps(c("start","complete"), format = dmy_hms) -> hospital
hospital %>%
  activitylog(case_id = "patient_visit_nr",
              activity_id = "activity",
              resource_id = "originator",
              timestamps = c("start", "complete")) -> hospital
hospital %>%
  detect_time_anomalies()
```

which gives

```
*** OUTPUT ***
For 5 rows in the activity log (9.43%), an anomaly is detected.
The anomalies are spread over the activities as follows:
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  activity      type                  n
  <chr>         <chr>             <int>
1 Registration  negative duration     3
2 Clinical exam zero duration         1
3 Trage         negative duration     1
Anomalies are found in the following rows:
# Log of 10 events consisting of:
3 traces 
3 cases 
5 instances of 3 activities 
5 resources 
Events occurred from 2017-11-21 11:22:16 until 2017-11-21 19:00:00 
 
# Variables were mapped as follows:
Case identifier:        patient_visit_nr 
Activity identifier:        activity 
Resource identifier:        originator 
Timestamps:     start, complete 

# A tibble: 5 × 10
  patient_visit_nr activity      originator start               complete            triagecode specialization .order durat…¹ type 
             <dbl> <chr>         <chr>      <dttm>              <dttm>                   <dbl> <chr>           <int>   <dbl> <chr>
1              518 Registration  Clerk 12   2017-11-21 11:45:16 2017-11-21 11:22:16          4 PED                 1  -23    nega…
2              518 Registration  Clerk 6    2017-11-21 11:45:16 2017-11-21 11:22:16          4 PED                 2  -23    nega…
3              518 Registration  Clerk 9    2017-11-21 11:45:16 2017-11-21 11:22:16          4 PED                 3  -23    nega…
4              520 Trage         Nurse 17   2017-11-21 13:43:16 2017-11-21 13:39:00          5 URG                 4   -4.27 nega…
5              528 Clinical exam Doctor 1   2017-11-21 19:00:00 2017-11-21 19:00:00          3 TRAU                5    0    zero…
# … with abbreviated variable name ¹​duration
```

I would like to save all thse outputs `(*** OUTPUT ***,# A tibble: 3 × 3,# Log of 10 events,# Variables were mapped as follows: consisting of:)` in a list in order to be able to extract the from there.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the last statement into `str()` and checking the output? If the output is not well structured, but rather printed, then you're out of luck. At least in the short term. You will have to modify `detect_time_anomalies()` to get a pretty result.

Comment: u mean str(hospital %>%
  detect_time_anomalies()) . yes but what do i get out of this?

Comment: Looking at the source code of `detect_time_anomalies()`, the only thing that is returned is the last tibble, while the rest is just printed using `message()` or `print()`. So you either have to modify the function to return also the other stuff as @RomanLuštrik suggests or copy parts of it that are of interest to you and compute what you need independently of the function.

Comment: Yepp, I [agree with Robert](https://github.com/bupaverse/daqapo/blob/master/R/detect_time_anomalies.R#L61).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of modifying the function to return all the desired output. My modifications start with `output <- list()`.

Oh, not tested.

```r
detect_time_anomalies <- function(activitylog, anomaly_type = c("both", "negative","zero") ,
                                  details = TRUE, filter_condition = NULL){
  
  # Predefine variables
  type <- NULL
  duration <- NULL
  activity <- NULL
  complete <- NULL
  start <- NULL
  anomaly_type <- match.arg(anomaly_type)
  # Generate warning if inappropriate anomaly type is selected
  
  
  # Apply filter condition when specified
  filter_specified <- FALSE
  tryCatch({
    is.null(filter_condition)
  }, error = function(e) {
    filter_specified <<- TRUE
  }
  )
  
  if(!filter_specified) {
    # geen filter gespecifieerd.
    
  } else {
    filter_condition_q <- enquo(filter_condition)
    activitylog <- APPLY_FILTER(activitylog, filter_condition_q = filter_condition_q)
  }
  
  # Calculate durations
  activitylog %>%
    mutate(duration = as.double(complete - start, units = "mins")) -> anomalies
  
  # Determine time anomalies
  if(anomaly_type == "negative"){
    anomalies <- anomalies %>% filter(duration < 0)
  } else if(anomaly_type == "zero"){
    anomalies <- anomalies %>% filter(duration == 0)
  } else{
    anomalies <- anomalies %>% filter(duration <= 0) %>%
      mutate(type = ifelse(duration < 0, "negative duration", "zero duration"))
  }
  
  output <- list()
  
  # Print output
  message("Selected anomaly type: ", anomaly_type, "\n")
  output$anomaly_type <- anomaly_type
  
  message("*** OUTPUT ***")
  output$percent_anomalies <- round(nrow(anomalies) / nrow(activitylog) * 100, 2)
  output$num_anomalies <- nrow(anomalies)
  message("For ", nrow(anomalies), " rows in the activity log (", output$percent_anomalies, "%), an anomaly is detected.")
  
  
  if(nrow(anomalies) > 0){
    message("The anomalies are spread over the activities as follows:")
    if(anomaly_type == "both"){
      output$both <- anomalies %>% group_by(!!activity_id_(activitylog), type) %>% summarize(n = n()) %>% arrange(desc(n))
      print(output$both)
    } else{
      output$other <- anomalies %>% group_by(!!activity_id_(activitylog)) %>% summarize(n = n()) %>% arrange(desc(n))
      print(output$other)
    }
    
    if(details == TRUE){
      message("Anomalies are found in the following rows:")
      output$details <- anomalies
      return(output$details)
    }
  }
```

Comment: how can I display this message as text in shiny? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74930866/display-message-from-function-as-text-in-a-shiny-app